# Is color intensity accumulative and will be converged to a certain value?

Tags: image-processing, printing

If I keep printing a dot with any certain color at the same position, will it turn out to be a black dot? Why?

Comment: No, if you repeatedly paint with yellow ink, you will get a yellow dot... followed some time later by a little pool of soggy yellow paper and an empty ink cartridge warning.

Comment: @MarkSetchell so why does the intensity of that area not go to 255 in each dimension with the accumulation of ink?

Comment: Are you talking about printing on actual paper? How are you measuring the intensity of ink on the paper - what with?

Comment: @MarkSetchell aha I konw what you are saying. There is no such digitalization and upper limit for a real world color as its analog property, so the black can not be just represented as (255,255,255), is it?

Comment: @David 255,255,255 usually represents white, not black...

Comment: @Piglet no `(255,255,255)` is black in substractive color space like CMY used for passive reflect/absorb colors. Active light source colors like RGB are white with `(255,255,255)`

Comment: @David that depends on printing technology. For inks you would saturate used channels so for example if you use yellow only it will be still yellow. gray should saturate to black though ... if chemical&physical properties allows it

Comment: @Spektre he did not mention any colour space and I said "usually". He did not mention CMYK at all. About your commend on gray. Gray is not a colour. His question is about colours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No! The dot will not turn out to be black.

Non-black printer ink only reflects light of its colour. The rest is absorbed.
Increasing the amount of ink on one spot will not affect the spectral reflectance of that spot.

You can only achieve a black spot by creating something that absorbs (nearly) all visible light. This can be achieved by mixing different inks or by using a black ink right away.

Colour mixing in printers is subtractive while RGB is an additive colour model.

Read this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractive_color

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_mixing

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model